# How to run Makefile from any directory?

Tags: bash, makefile

I have created a makefile which is fully automatic. This means, I do not need to change makefile to run different programs.

Now what I want to do is put that makefile somewhere and call that makefile from directory where my program is. But condition is that makefile should run as if I have putted that makefile in directory where my program is created and NOT at place where makefile actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a Makefile from another location as if it was in the current directory with:

```
make -f /path/to/your/makefile
```

You can make an alias or function for it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run it this way and supply any arguments:

```
make -C path/to/your/directory argument
```